# Including file generated in BeforeBuild to the compile list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Following is my MSBuild XML.  The file generated in BeforeBuild is NOT included in DLL.  I was expecting the file to included.  I do notice that CoreBuild was called in BeforeBuild.  How do I do a rebuild again including the generated file.

Thanks

Chris

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    ...
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    ...
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    ...
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include=".\Resources\Assembly\*.dll" Condition="Exists('.\Resources\Assembly')" />
    ...
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include=".\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="EdmTasks.ViewRefreshTask" AssemblyFile=".\Resources\Assembly\EdmTasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MsBuild Projects="ForwardPAS.csproj" Targets="CoreBuild" />
    <ViewRefreshTask Assembly="$(TargetPath)" Lang="cs" DbContext="FranklinIndexedAnnuityDb" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: 1. Where are you including the generated assembly to the assembly going to be built by the CoreBuild. 2. We should say that CoreBuild is dependent on BeforeBuild so that MSBuild won't execute them parallely.

Comment: My task ViewRefreshTask needs CoreBuild to happen...since it uses the DLL.  Then it generates a CS file.  What I want to happen is, is that the generated CS file get 'included' in the project...so after BeforeBuild finishes and Build comes along it now build the generated file into the DLL.

Comment: I added a Task to run MsBuild (Target:CoreBuild) to BeforeBuild to do a rebuild...here are the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MsBuild Projects="MyProject.csproj" Targets="CoreBuild" />
    <ViewRefreshTask Assembly="$(TargetPath)" Lang="cs" DbContext="MyDatabaseContext" />
    <MsBuild Projects="MyProject.csproj" Targets="CoreBuild" Properties="Rerun=true" />
</Target>
```

1. The steps taken during a build are
       a.  BeforeBuild
       b.  Build (includes CoreBuild)
       c.  AfterBuild
2. Since we need MyDatabase.Views.cs to be built in the MyProject.DLL, we have to generate it before we reach Build (b)…so we place it in BeforeBuild (a)
3. But ViewRefreskTask (that generates this file) needs the MyProject.DLL as input…so before the ViewRefreskTask we call “CoreBuild” (to build the MyProject.dll)
4. I initially assumed that when BeforeBuild finished it will move on to Build and rebuild the Project (since there is a new file is the Compile ItemGroup)…but it didn’t…it just gave a message “Target "CoreBuild" skipped. Previously built successfully.”
5. So I added a new Task  … this still gave me “Target "CoreBuild" skipped. Previously built successfully.”
6. Finally, thanks to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/8db6b9e4-16dd-48b2-b243-c6e4c9670982/ I added Properties="Rerun=true" and it worked.

It did a rebuild and the project DLL had my generated Views.

Answer (score 0):

Directly after the csharp targets line

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Add this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>False</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

VS will grab the source again to compile, rather than using a cached version from when the build process started.